# When running under IIS Express I must recompile each time I change something in a .cshtml file?

Tags: visual-studio

We've recently changed from the built-in VS.NET Development Webserver to IIS Express, but now we are experiencing a wierd issue where, every time we change a .cshtml file, the webserver complains about not being able to read resources files:

An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Error reading resource file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f8182027\1ae20e7e\ResX\resources.resetpassword.nb-no.resources' -- 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

A recompile solves the issue, but it's annoying as heck.

Anyone have any clues as how to resolve this?